# AMC 12A, problem with days

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

In year N, the $300th$ day of the year is a Tuesday. In year $N+1$, the $200th$ 
day is also a Tuesday. On what day of the week did the $100th$ day of year $N - 1$ occur? 
(2000 AMC 10 #25)

The answer is: **Thursday.**

The answer can be done using Modulus. Consider this (modulo 7):

Monday - 1

Tuesday - 2

Wednesday - 3

Thursday - 4

Friday - 5

Saturday - 6

Sunday - 7

$$200 \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$$

$$300 \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$$

I dont get it now.....

Help?

Answer (score 1):

The 200th day of Year $N+1$ is either 365-100=265 or 366-100=266 days after the 300th day of Year $N$.  This is a whole number of weeks.  So was a Leap Year involved?
How many days earlier was the 100th day of Year $N-1$?

Comment: How do I know if a leap year was there?

Comment: Which of 265 or 266 days can be a whole number of weeks?

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote the $300th$ thay in $N$ with $x$, then we have:

$$x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$

Now let's assume there are $65$ days until the end of the year, so we have:

$$x+65+200 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$
$$x+265 \equiv x \pmod 7$$
$$265 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

Contradiction, hence $N$ is leap year, and what's more $N-1$ can't be a leap year.

Now denote the $100th$ day of $N-1$ with $y$, then we have:

$$y+265+300 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$
$$y-1-1\equiv 2 \pmod 7$$
$$y \equiv 4 \pmod 7$$

Hence the 100th day in $N-1$ was Thursday